# Obtener los 12 unicos caracteres juntos

Tags: c#, caracteres

Tengo una cadena de texto que contiene varios conjuntos de letras, necesito extraer la palabra con 12 caracteres (la Mac Address) y lo demas almacenarlo en otra variable, sin tener que ver con su posicion.

```
string x = "AXIS CAMERA - ACCC8E533101  HOSTNAME    Layer 2";
```

Cuando me refiero a no tener que ver con su posicion quiero decir que el codigo pueda extraerlo sin importar que sea el primero, el segundo o el tecero como en estos casos:

```
string x1 = "ACCC8E533101 - AXIS CAMERA HOSTNAME    Layer 2";
string x2 = "AXIS ACCC8E533101 CAMERA  Layer 2 HOSTNAME";
string x3 = " AXIS CAMERA ACCC8E533101 HOSTNAME Layer 2";
```

Comment: La Mac Address no llevaría ningún separador?

Comment: Antes si, pero yo se los quito porque hay sitios donde se usan con : y otros con -. Por esa razon las Mac address las uso asi.

Comment: Lo comente porque así sería mas complicado encontrar la Mac, ya que puede haber una coincidencia con cualquier cadena que tenga 12 caracteres

Comment: Sii, que problema tengo. Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un escaner capa 2 y me lanza la mac address, el nombre del dispositivo y el host todo junto en una misma linea.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que no importa que formato reciba la mac adress, ya sea .(punto) o -(guion) y usar una regex para buscar la mac en esos formatos

Comment: Estoy usando un regex, pero no recibo la otra parte de la cadena osea lo que no es la Mac address.

Comment: Intentaste algo?

Comment: var regex = "([0-9A-Fa-f]{12})"; // 12 caracteres numericos o letras de la A la F
          string mac = Regex.Match(x1, regex).ToString();

Comment: Eso me guarda los 12 caracteres juntos, pero no los sobrantes.

Comment: Y tu deseas que se guarde todo? No entendi esa parte

Comment: sigo sin entender,¿ podrías reformular la pregunta con lo que quieres obtener y lo que has intentado, por favor?

Comment: @fredyfx por un lado quiere la MacAddress y en otra variable capturar el resto del string, puso 3 ejemplos porque no siempre vendra en el mismo orden la MacAddress

Comment: @RamiroBarone Exacto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta una simple función:

```
static string GetMacString(string p_Text)
{
    // Extraemos las subcadenas del texto, con el espacio
    // como separador.
    string[] subStrings = p_Text.Split(' ');
    // Buscamos la que tiene 12 caracteres
    for(int i=0; i < subStrings.Length; i++)
    {
      if (subStrings[i].Length == 12)
          return subStrings[i];
    }
  
    return "";
}
```

Devolverá la primera cadena de texto con 12 caracteres o texto vacío si no la encuentra.